# How to put paragraph inside div in one line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put paragraph text inside `div` and display it in single line. If the text is longer then specified width it should not go to second line (outside of div).
I tried everything in CSS, used `text-overflow` and `white-space` but without any success.
This is part of my html:

```
   <li>
    <a href="#" id="searchLink">

        <div id="searchDiv">
            <img id="searchImg" src="" />
            <p id="searchedProductName">
            </p>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

If I put some longer text in paragraf using jQuery text uses 2 lines, (goes outside of the div)
My CSS:

```
    #searchDiv {
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 600px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;

}
   #searchImg {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#searchedProductName {
     text-overflow: ellipsis; /* will make [...] at the end */
width: 370px; /* change to your preferences */
white-space: nowrap; /* paragraph to one line */
overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
}
```

I solved the problem of displaying line, with newly updated CSS but paragragh still goes outside the `div`.

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float:left` to your image and `display:inline-block` to container div.

```
#searchDiv {
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#searchImg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float:left;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fMvLp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

put

```
overflow: hidden;
```

in the SearchDiv